# 2nd where being case sensitive in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a construct function in my Laravel Excel Import to save resources.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->employees = EmployeeInformation::where('company_id', Auth::user()
                                          ->company_id)
                                          ->select('id', 'employee_number')->get();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is when I use `$this->employees` to get the 1 record is it becomes case sensitive. for e.g. the `Employee Number` is `EMP1`

This returns the employee.

```
$this->employees->where('employee_number', 'EMP1')->first();
```

This returns null.

```
$this->employees->where('employee_number', 'emp1')->first();
```

Is there any work around this to save resources? What I want to achieve is using the `$this->employees` to search through the record of the employee to avoid querying per row in my importing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE %...%

```
$this->employees->where('employee_number', 'LIKE', '%emp1%')->first();
```

Comment: Is it still null?

Comment: Yes when I try to put "LIKE", its still case sensitive and % doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the the Upper/Lower function in this case.

```
$this->employees->where('employee_number', 'LIKE', '%'.strtoupper($value).'%')->first();
```